# What properties of metric spaces are not preserved by uniformly continuous isomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity, uniform-spaces

Compactness and connectedness are preserved by homeomorphism, in the sense that if two metric spaces $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ are homeomorphic and $(X,d_X)$ is compact then it follows that $(Y,d_Y)$ is also compact (and similarly for connectedness). However, if $(X,d_X)$ is complete it does not necessarily follow that $(X,d_Y)$ is also complete (to see this, we can take $X = \mathbb{N}$ and $Y = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}\}$, both with the usual metric). In fact the same counterexample can be used to show that boundedness is not preserved by homeomorphism.

On the other hand, it can be shown that *uniformly continuous isomorphism* preserves compactness, connectedness, completeness and boundedness, in the sense that if there exists a uniformly continuous bijection $f:(X,d_X) \rightarrow (Y,d_Y)$ whose inverse is uniformly continuous and $(X,d_X)$ has one of the properties listed earlier, than $(Y,d_Y)$ also has that property.

Compactness, connectedness, completeness and boundedness are all properties which seem "important" in some sense in the context of metric spaces. So are there any other "important" properties that metric spaces can have which are not preserved by uniformly continuous isomorphism?

Comment: Most "fine" geometric properties are not preserved. For instance, property of being a path-metric space, uniqueness of geodesics, Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: What do you mean by "isomorphism"? Under the usual understanding of this term, all properties of a metric space are preserved under an isomorphism.

Comment: @RobArthan I already mentioned in the question what I mean by uniformly continuous isomorphism (a uniformly continuous bijection with a uniformly continuous inverse). As was pointed out by Moishe Kohan, not all properties of metric spaces are preserved by uniformly continuous isomorphism.

Comment: Your phrasing doesn't make it clear that you are giving a definition (the phrase "in the sense that" isn't in the right place for that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not know any of the properties/invariants listed below, but these are important in the theory of metric spaces. Here are some examples:

1. [Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) is not preserved by uniformly continuous isomorphisms. For instance, you can have a compact metric space $(X_1,d_1)$ of zero Hausdorff dimension and a compact metric space $(X_2,d_2)$ of infinite Hausdorff dimension, such that $X_1$ is homeomorphic to $X_2$.
2. A metric space $(X,d)$ is called a [path-metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric) if for any two points $x,y\in X$, $d(x,y)$ equals infimum of lengths of paths in $X$ connecting $x$ to $y$. (Another name is an **intrinsic** metric space.) You can have two homeomorphic metric compacts $(X_1,d_1)$, $(X_2,d_2)$ such that the first one is a path-metric space while the second contains no rectifiable nonconstant paths.
3. You can have two countably-infinite metric spaces  $(X_1,d_1)$, $(X_2,d_2)$ both of which have discrete topology and satisfy $d_i(x,y)\ge 1$ for all $x\ne y$, such that the first one is [hyperbolic in the sense of Gromov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_metric_space) (where hyperbolicity is defined via Gromov-products) and the second is not. But, $(X_1,d_1)$, $(X_2,d_2)$ are isomorphic via a uniformly continuous homeomorphism (any bijection $X_1\to X_2$ will do the job).
4. [Quasi-isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry) type is not preserved by a uniformly continuous homeomorphism: You can have two countably-infinite metric spaces  $(X_1,d_1)$, $(X_2,d_2)$ both of which have discrete topology and satisfy $d_i(x,y)\ge 1$ for all $x\ne y$, such that $(X_1,d_1)$, $(X_2,d_2)$ are not quasi-isometric to each other. However, as in (3), there is a uniformly continuous isomorphism of these metric spaces.

Comment: $+1$, great answer! In $1$. and $2$., where you write “homeomorphic”, do you mean “isomorphic via a uniformly continuous homemorphism” (as you wrote in $3$.)? Because otherwise those statements wouldn’t seem relevant to the question.

Comment: @joriki: In view of compactness, it does not matter: a continuous map of compact metric spaces is necessarily uniformly continuous.